# curl SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO alert handshake error

Tags: ssl, curl, tls1.2

I wish to call an API on a web server using curl command line tool but I get the following error:

```
C:\src>curl -v -u username:password https://10.51.50.66:9443/api/eula

*   Trying 10.51.50.66...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.51.50.66 (10.51.50.66) port 9443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection:ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Are there any options I can add to curl command to solve this?

Comment: Please provie the output as text in your question, not as an inlined image, for better readability, searchability, etc.

Comment: To do proper HTTPS you will need to use URLs with hostnames... Message unknown number 21 is the certificate_url extension, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6066#section-5 but it should be sent by client, not server.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: I think that's an incorrect decode. _handshake_ type 21 is CertURL, but _record_ type 21 is alert, and the error proves we are receiving an alert, apparently with level 2=fatal misdecoded as ServerHello. and description handshake_failure -- which tells us very little. HARRY: can you check with the server log(s) and/or admin(s) what it thinks the problem is? Is the server using SNI, in which case you probably need to use the (DNS)name instead of the address?

Comment: Similar problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192953 - It boils down to explicitely use SSLv2 and/or upgrade curl. Maybe it helps.